# :not() selector on CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a problem with the :not() selector on CSS.

I have this code:

```
<div class="group">
    <div role="layer" class="one">Layer</div>
    <div role="layer" class="two">Layer</div>
    <div role="layer" class="three">Layer</div>
    <div role="layer" class="four">Layer</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
div[role="layer"]{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.group > [role="layer"]:first-child{
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.group > [role="layer"]:last-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.group [role="layer"]:not(:first-child){
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QRGND/)

What I want to do is to make the first and last layer to have rounded corners but not the other layer. As you can see I can make the first layer not to have a border radius, but when the :not(:first-child) selector is applied, it makes the last layer to change.

If someone can understand my point, I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is say "layers that are neither the first child nor the last child should have `border-radius: 0`". You can achieve this by having multiple `:not()` selectors:

```
.group [role="layer"]:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRGND/2/)

Comment: God. I swear to God I tried that many time and it didn't work... But thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need 2 changes here:

1. Move the last CSS declaration (the one with :not) up above the :last-child declaration (in CSS order matters)
2. Replace

   ```
   .group > [role="layer"]:last-child {
       border-top-left-radius: 0;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   .group > [role="layer"]:last-child {
       border-top-right-radius: 5px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   }
   ```